# Freeze gridview pager while scrolling vertically

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview, paging, scrollable

I have a gridview.
I have to implement both Paging as well as make the page scrollable both horizontally and vertically. The page navigation bar comes at the bottom.

While scrolling the page vertically, I want two things -

1. The gridview headers should also be frozen.
2. gridview pagers should also be frozen.

I mean they should not scroll along with the data.
Only the rows should scroll.

I have implemented -
1. Fixed header using CSS
2. Horizontally scrollable using CSS
3. Vertically scrollable using CSS

I am not able to
1. Fix the Pager.

My code:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<style type="text/css">
    div#gvResultStyle
    {
        width: 500px;
        height: 350px;
        overflow: scroll;
        position: relative;
    }

    div#gvResultStyle th
    {
        background-color: Navy;
        color: White;
        top: expression(document.getElementById("gvResultStyle").scrollTop-2);
        left: expression(parentNode.scrollLeft);
        position: relative;
        z-index: 20;
    }

    .gvPager
    {
        left: 0px;
        width: 400px;
        border-right-style: solid;
        position: absolute;
        height: 10px;
        text-align: left;
        border-right-color: Navy;
    }
</style>
```

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<h2>
    Welcome to ASP.NET!
</h2>
<p>
    To learn more about ASP.NET visit <a href="http://www.asp.net" title="ASP.NET Website">
        www.asp.net</a>.
</p>
<p>
    You can also find <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=152368&amp;clcid=0x409"
        title="MSDN ASP.NET Docs">documentation on ASP.NET at MSDN</a>.
</p>
<div id="gvResultStyle">
<asp:GridView ID="gvCustomers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ProductID"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" CssClass="gvResultStyle">
    <PagerSettings Position="Bottom" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gvPager" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductID" HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False"
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ProductID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SupplierID" HeaderText="SupplierID" SortExpression="SupplierID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="QuantityPerUnit" HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="UnitPrice" SortExpression="UnitPrice" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsInStock" HeaderText="UnitsInStock" SortExpression="UnitsInStock" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitsOnOrder" HeaderText="UnitsOnOrder" SortExpression="UnitsOnOrder" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ReorderLevel" HeaderText="ReorderLevel" SortExpression="ReorderLevel" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="Discontinued" HeaderText="Discontinued" SortExpression="Discontinued" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" SortExpression="CategoryName" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Alphabetical list of products]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, it can be apply to GridView.
see the image:

[image]

It also support pager:

Demo: [Pager Support](http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo/Support.aspx#Pager)

Comment: Took a look at your site. But where is this file `gridviewScroll.min.js`?